# Find the general term of the sequence $a_n = a_{n-1}^2 +1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

I need to find the general rule of the sequence $1,2,5,26,677,...$  I know that the recursive definition is $a_n = a_{n-1}^2 +1$.

Could someone please explain HOW to get to the general form.  Not WHAT it is.  Thanks.

Comment: More information can be obtained by looking at A003095 in the Oeis.

Comment: I found that entry, but quite frankly could find the answer anywhere there.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that a closed form is possible.

For the simpler sequence

$$b_n=b_{n-1}^2$$

the general term is

$$b_n=(b_0)^{2^n}$$

which gives you a first asymptotic estimate.

As for large $a_n$ the term $1$ is neglectible, you can use this approximation of your sequence

$$a_n=(a_k)^{2^{n-k}}$$ for some $k<n$.

Now if you consider the expression

$$\sqrt[2^n]{a_n},$$ it tends to a constant, about $c=1.2259024$, and $a_n\approx c^{2^n}$.

---

After a little more research, it turns out that a closed formula is

$$\color{green}{a_n=\left\lfloor c^{2^n}\right\rfloor}$$ where

$$c=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2^n]a_n,$$ because the approximation is so good that the error is always smaller than one unit, by excess.

Comment: How did you get the general term?

Comment: Huh. I always thought quadratic recurrence relations other than $x_{n+1}=x_n^2$ were all hopelessly unsolvable.

Comment: @JackM - They are really, but many of these so-called *doubly exponential sequences* are close enough to $k^{2^n}$ for some $k$ that you can find a type of solution by finding the particular $k$ to enough digits to look impressive and some of these $k$s are related.  See for example [OEIS A004019](https://oeis.org/A004019) with $2.25851845058946539883779624\ldots$ which is the $4$th power of $1.2259024435287485\ldots$ here. It does not help much, since the calculation of $k$ depends on the sequence more than the other way round.

Comment: @Henry: How would one find the general form?  I know the general form is in the answer, but how does one come up with that number?

Comment: @Henry: maybe there's some hope to compute the constant by other means.

Comment: @Guest: the calculations are as simple as $\sqrt[32]{677}$ and $\sqrt[64]{458330}$ etc.  Proofs are a little longer, as you have to consider the errors. https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/11-4/aho-a.pdf has some discussion

Comment: @Yves: What happened to the plus one?

Comment: @Guest: nothing, why ?

Comment: How did you go from the recursive definition to the general rule?

Comment: @Guest: iterated squarings.

Comment: @Yves: Would it be possible to use a graphing calculator to go from the recursive definition to the general term?

Comment: @Yves: I still don't know where the $+1$ from the recursive definition went when you wrote the "simpler sequence."  To my eye, the simpler sequence simply the recursive definition without the $+1$.

Comment: @Guest: if I say simpler, doesn't that mean that I changed something ?????